# Do custom trigger persistence delegates have to be included in quartz.dll?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

A special requirement led me to implement a custom trigger in quartz.net. (Version 2.3.0)

The problem I have is registering the appropriate persistence delegate.

There is

- Main project, which references the required Quartz.dll and starts up an instance of the scheduler
- Core project is referenced by the "Main project" and extends that project in functionality that can be accessed by other projects, too

Now the "Core project" is where I declared both the custom trigger implementation and the belonging custom persistence delegate.

In "Main project" configuration data for the scheduler instance is provided via config file, here I added:

`<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateInitString" value="triggerPersistenceDelegateClasses=SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate, SolutionName.QuartzService.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />`

(I also tried with `SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate` before that)

When I start up the scheduler I see that the try to register that persistence delegate fails:

```
Unhandled Exception: Quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. ---> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't instantiate delegate: Error instantiating TriggerPersistenceDelegate of type: SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate ---> Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.NoSuchDelegateException: Error instantiating TriggerPersistenceDelegate of type: SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate' from assembly 'Quartz, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The `Quartz`-assembly being explicitly mentioned got me confused. Do I have to compile Quartz-source code including my custom persistence delegate so that it is found? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is obviously: **no.**

In my case it seems I just used the wrong setting-name.

I replaced

`<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateInitString" value="triggerPersistenceDelegateClasses=SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate, SolutionName.QuartzService.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />`

with

`<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateInitString" value="triggerPersistenceDelegateTypes=SolutionName.QuartzService.Core.Triggers.CustomTriggerPersistenceDelegate, SolutionName.QuartzService.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />`

and now there are no more complaints from the scheduler starting up.